# How to use a int variable inside a RegEx pattern?

Tags: javascript

I wan to replace a regex value with a int value:

```
const decimal = 16;
const amount = 100;
if (amount.match(/^\d{1,}(\.\d{0,8})?$/)) // how can I replace 8 with decimal value 16
```

How can I replace the 8 with the decimal value?

Comment: What does `decimal` look like after the replacement?

Comment: Amount must not have {decimal value} decimal.

Comment: I mean no disrespect, but I have read over this a few times and I am still very unclear on what you are asking.  It would be helpful if you gave a clear example (or perhaps a few examples) of inputs and expected outputs for your use case.

Comment: amount.match(/^\d{1,}(\.\d{0,8})?$/), replace the 8 with the value decimal = 16

Comment: can you make it more clear please? I can help if you provide the example + the result expected

Comment: My question is How to use a decimal variable inside a RegEx pattern /^\d{1,}(\.\d{0,[[decimal value here]]})?$/?

Comment: so you want to match a string then replace the matched part with the decimal part right?

Comment: Yes, just want to get the decimal variable into the regex

Comment: `amount` needs to be a string for this to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor accepts a string to create the pattern out of it. You can construct the string however you want:

```js
const decimal = 16;
const amount = 100;
const regexp = new RegExp('^\\d{1,}(\\.\\d{0,' + decimal + '})?$');

if (amount.toString().match(regexp)) // do further work
```

Comment: the amount can be in decimal, if it is converted into string... may have problem?

Comment: @Alvin -- that shouldn't be a problem for the regexp matching. Please note that I've just observed that my previous answer was incorrect, as you need to escape backslashes in the string. I've updated the answer now.

Comment: I took away toString(), it works correctly. I may need to test a few times.

Answer (score -1):

I think you might want to check this [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
const myText = "some text with the word dog to match it";
const regex = /dog/gi;
myText.replace(regex, 'MY DECIMAL');
```

or instead of making your pattern as regex /pat/

```
const re = new RegExp("\\w+");
```

& use `+` to add decimal to it. (You can use decimal as a string)